# UDF and python function in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe in Pyspark as:

```
listA = [(1,'AAA','USA'),(2,'XXX','CHN'),(3,'KKK','USA'),(4,'PPP','USA'),(5,'EEE','USA'),(5,'HHH','THA')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(listA, ['id', 'name','country'])
```

and I have created a dictionary as:

```
thedict={"USA":"WASHINGTON","CHN":"BEIJING","DEFAULT":"KEY NOT FOUND"}
```

and Then I created a UDF to get the matching key values from dictionary.

```
def my_func(letter):
    if(thedict.get(letter) !=None):
        return thedict.get(letter)
    else:
        return thedict.get("DEFAULT")
```

I am getting below error when trying to call function as:

```
df.withColumn('CAPITAL',my_func(df.country))

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1848, in withColumn
    assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Whereas if I embedded it with pyspark.sql.functions, it's working fine.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
udfdict = udf(my_func,StringType())

df.withColumn('CAPITAL',udfdict(df.country)).show()

+---+----+-------+-------------+
| id|name|country|      CAPITAL|
+---+----+-------+-------------+
|  1| AAA|    USA|   WASHINGTON|
|  2| XXX|    CHN|      BEIJING|
|  3| KKK|    USA|   WASHINGTON|
|  4| PPP|    USA|   WASHINGTON|
|  5| EEE|    USA|   WASHINGTON|
|  5| HHH|    THA|KEY NOT FOUND|
+---+----+-------+-------------+
```

I couldn't understand what is the difference in these two calls?

Comment: Every function that you wrote and need to be applied on columns, you have to transform it to an pyspark `UDF` and then use it!

Comment: @Ali. That doesn't seems to be true. see below code. It's working fine. listA = [('A',10,20,40,60),('B',10,10,10,40)]     
df = spark.createDataFrame(listA, ['id', 'M1','M2','M3','M4'])

def add_column(*args):
    num=0
    for i in args:
        num = num +i
    return  num
    
newdf = df.withColumn('TOTAL', add_column(df.M1,df.M2,df.M3))

Comment: no I have created a python udf as :def add_column(*args):
    num=0
    for i in args:
        num = num +i
    return  num

Comment: Yeah, I see that. have you tried any functions like `add_column` and without using `udf` apply it on columns?

Comment: yes. :-(  I did and it's working fine. It's not working in the problem explained above. when I am trying to get the values from dictionary. is it happening because of the return type?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the problem, but I suggest you use `udf` to your work gets done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDF functions have special properties in that they take column/s and apply the logic row-wise to produce a new column. whereas a common python function takes only one discrete argument and produces a single output.

And thats what the error is about. The returned value from function is not a column

> assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"

You can define udf in two ways:

1. myudf = udf(LAMBDA_EXPRESSION, RETURN_TYPE )
2. myudf = udf(CUSTOM_FUNCTION, RETURN_TYPE)

Comment: I get that and thanks for ur input. But why it's working in the example explained above in comment section. There also I am calling python function using withCoulmn and passing multiple arguments to it. Am I missing something ?